# Xcode 14: Custom templates don't appear in Swift Package file creation

Tags: swift, xcode, templates, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I created custom files templates for my Xcode projects.

In a normal project environment my custom templates appear when I access the `New file` creation popover as you can see in the following screenshoot

[image]

These templates are located at the common path of: `/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates`

The problem appear when I'm working on a swift package.
When I try to create a new file the popover interface is very different and does not contain my custom templates as seen with in the following image:

[image]

My suspicion is that I should set my templates in an other specific location for swift packages but I don't know where. I have looked around and I don't seems to find any reference to where I should set custom content for `Swift Packages`.

I'm looking for any tips on that matter. Or any information that could give me a some clues on how to fix my issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently there is a new field that needs to be set to make a template avaliable for the Swift Package

Just add

```
<key>SupportsSwiftPackage</key>
<true/>
```

to your TemplateInfo.plist

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @KamilZaborowski, this seems to do the trick.